# Google Geocoding API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT issue

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm trying to run a script to change addresses (around 1,000) into geo coordinates but for some reason I'm getting an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response after hitting the 50th address in my input list.

To avoid the query limit I already added a time.sleep command in the loop but for some reason it says I'm over limit again.

Can anyone help? (FYI, I'm running it on my laptop)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import logging
import time
logger = logging.getLogger("root")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(ch)

API_KEY = my_key #using my API key
BACKOFF_TIME = 5
output_filename = 'result.csv'
input_filename = 'input.csv'
address_column_name = "Address"
RETURN_FULL_RESULTS = False

data = pd.read_csv(input_filename, encoding='utf8')
if address_column_name not in data.columns:
raise ValueError("Missing Address column in input data")
addresses = data[address_column_name].tolist()

def get_google_results(address, api_key=my_key, return_full_response=False):
geocode_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={}".format(address)
if api_key is not None:
    geocode_url = geocode_url + "&key={}".format(api_key)

results = requests.get(geocode_url)
results = results.json()

if len(results['results']) == 0:
    output = {
        "formatted_address" : None,
        "latitude": None,
        "longitude": None,
        "accuracy": None,
        "google_place_id": None,
        "type": None,
        "postcode": None
    }
else:
    answer = results['results'][0]
    output = {
        "formatted_address" : answer.get('formatted_address'),
        "latitude": answer.get('geometry').get('location').get('lat'),
        "longitude": answer.get('geometry').get('location').get('lng'),
        "accuracy": answer.get('geometry').get('location_type'),
        "google_place_id": answer.get("place_id"),
        "type": ",".join(answer.get('types')),
        "postcode": ",".join([x['long_name'] for x in answer.get('address_components')
                              if 'postal_code' in x.get('types')])
    }

output['input_string'] = address
output['number_of_results'] = len(results['results'])
output['status'] = results.get('status')
if return_full_response is True:
    output['response'] = results

return output

results = []
for address in addresses:
  geocoded = False
  while geocoded is not True:
      try:
        geocode_result = get_google_results(address, API_KEY, 
return_full_response=RETURN_FULL_RESULTS)
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        logger.error("Major error with {}".format(address))
        logger.error("Skipping!")
        geocoded = True
    if geocode_result['status'] == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT':
        logger.info("Hit Query Limit! Backing off for a bit.")
        time.sleep(BACKOFF_TIME * 60) # sleep
        geocoded = False
    else:
        if geocode_result['status'] != 'OK':
            logger.warning("Error geocoding {}: {}".format(address, geocode_result['status']))
        logger.debug("Geocoded: {}: {}".format(address, geocode_result['status']))
        results.append(geocode_result)
        geocoded = True

if len(results) % 100 == 0:
    logger.info("Completed {} of {} address".format(len(results), len(addresses)))

if len(results) % 50 == 0:
    pd.DataFrame(results).to_csv("{}_bak".format(output_filename))

logger.info("Finished geocoding all addresses")
pd.DataFrame(results).to_csv(output_filename, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "warning after running approximately 50 lines". How do you come on this conclusion. Are you debugging it line by line. If yes , then which exact part of code is throwing the error?  How many total request you are sending ? Google also has a daily query limit.

Comment: @shiva sorry for the vague expression. I'm getting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response from the API once hitting the 50th address in my input list.

Comment: Found any solutions? Have pretty much same issue

Comment: Hey @SimonGIS. I used the python library (link in the answer) to revise my code and it worked!

Comment: @lacroixant Im not sure to understand whats the difference you can find my code here https://github.com/renauld94/Python/blob/master/Geocoding.py. So basically, my request have to be done from the ''googlemaps'' library. The way my code is structure it sleeps for every 3 seconds... Why I will over query limit? Thanks for the help

Comment: @SimonGIS try using this code instead of your api key/function define 

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geocoding API has a queries per second (QPS) limit. You cannot send more than 50 QPS.

This limit is documented at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits

> While you are no longer limited to a maximum number of requests per day (QPD), the following usage limits are still in place for the Geocoding API:
>
> - 50 requests per second (QPS), calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

In order to solve your issue I would suggest using the Python client library for Google Maps API Web Services:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

This library controls QPS internally, so your requests will be queued properly.

I hope this helps!